# Custom Post Type Set Comments ON by default without show METABOX

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, taxonomy

I've created a new custom post type for a specific posts. The posts from my new custom post type, have - by default - set the comments to "off". I need to the comments to be "on" by default.

In my `functions.php` file I have this:

```
'supports' => array('editor','comments')
```

and

```
function default_comments_on( $data ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'registro' && $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' ) {
        $data['comment_status'] = 1;
    } 

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_on' );
```

But it didn't mark the box to comment by default. Any tips?

My default posts, don't show the metabox for comments, and the comments are allowed by default. I want to do exactly this with my new custom post type. I mean: Don't show the metabox and turn Comments on by default.

The register:

```
function create_post_type_registro() {

/**
 * Labels customizados para o tipo de post
 * 
 */
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Registros', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Registro', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Adicionar novo', 'film'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar novo registro'),
    'edit_item' => __('Editar registro'),
    'new_item' => __('Novo registro'),
    'all_items' => __('Todos os registros'),
    'view_item' => __('Ver registro'),
    'search_items' => __('Procurar registros'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nenhum registro encontrado'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nenhum registro encontrado na lixeira'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Registros'
);

/**
 * Registamos o tipo de post registro através desta função
 * passando-lhe os labels e parâmetros de controle.
 */
register_post_type( 'registro', array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,   
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'has_archive' => 'registros',
    'rewrite' => array(
     'slug' => 'registros',
     'with_front' => false,
    ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('editor','comments')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types support comments by default. I'm not sure how you registered your post type since you didn't include the full source but the [codex has good examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) on how to do that.

If the metabox is showing in your custom post type and you are trying to hide it you could click on Screen Options in the top right of your browser and uncheck <strike>comments</strike> discussion. This just hides the comment metabox in the edit screen.

[image]

Make sure you are including the comment template part in your single.php or page.php.

**====== Edit 2 - Correct answer ======**

After looking into this further it looks like something is overriding the comment status. Putting the below functions will do what you want

```
// Sets the comments to allowed by default
function turn_on_comments() { 
   update_option('default_comment_status', 'open');
} 
add_action('update_option', 'turn_on_comments');

// Hides the metabox in the edit screen (replace post-type-here with your custom post type)
function remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post-type-here', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_meta_boxes');
```

Comment: As i said i'm new in wordpress, so i dont know how to explain to you how i registered it. But,i'll try to explain it better.

Categories metabox, i can show and hide , removing it from supports array ... thats not my problem.

The problem is: By default for my custom post type, the select box to allow comments are not selected, so the poster need to click to allow comments. I need it to be selected as default, allowing comments without select it. 

My posts (the default post type), works this way, and plus it doesnt shows the metabox. I want it for my custom post type.

Sorry, my english sucks

Comment: I put the register code on the Answer - @kel

Comment: @Leibovich Under Settings > Discussions is "Allow people to post comments on new articles" checked? Make sure it is, this is what makes the Allow comments option to be checked by default.

Comment: Yes.. its checked... i already unchecked , save, checked again and save again,... =/

BTW ... i'm using 3.1.2

Comment: There might be something in a plugin or theme that is overriding that. If you look at my Edit 2 I added the option to hopefully force it checked.

Comment: Thank you alot. Worked. I can go on with that, but to be 100%, i need something more...

To work, i still need the 'comments' inside the supports array: 'supports' => array('editor','comments')

And this creates a metabox, right? So i need to "hide" this metabox.. theres a way ?

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. I have updated my answer with another function that will hide the metabox. You will need to change where it says post-type-here with registro. If you have more than one custom post type you will just copy that line and change the post type name.

Comment: This one didn't worked.

function remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'registro', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_meta_boxes');

Comment: Try changing out commentstatusdiv with commentsdiv. Here are all the meta boxes: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Comment: Nothing... I took a look at the debbuger too... commentstatusdiv seams right... but didn't worked.

Maybe its because the version? 3.1.2

Comment: I see the problem now... in admin panel, that worked... but i'm posting from the front-end...

Comment: Im using the same categories from my default post type on my custom post type. Do you know a way to filter the categories for the custom post type? I mean.. i dont want to list ALL categories, just some on the custom post type

Comment: @Leibovich I haven't messed with a front-end editor plugin so I don't know how to help you on that. If I were you I would search the plugin's code for add_meta_boxes and see if you can find where the metabox is being created. Here is more info on metaboxes: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box -- I'm not sure how to do the other manually but this plugin may help you out: http://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is not working for me and I think it can not work for most people. Even if it works for someone, it overrides the WordPress configuration site-wide and it is not specific for the required custom post type.

For me, the correct way to enable comments in a custom post type and remove the comments status meta box is something like this (assuming post type is registered with support for comments):

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'cyb_remove_meta_boxes');
function cyb_remove_meta_boxes() {

    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post-type-here', 'normal');

}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'cyb_comments_on' );
function cyb_comments_on( $data ) {

    if( $data['post_type'] == 'post-type-here' ) {

        $data['comment_status'] = "open";

    }

    return $data;

}
```

Or, maybe better, if we want to allow editors to close comments:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'cyb_remove_meta_boxes');
function cyb_remove_meta_boxes() {

    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {

        remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post-type-here', 'normal');
        add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'cyb_comments_on' );

    }


}

function cyb_comments_on( $data ) {

    if( $data['post_type'] == 'post-type-here' ) {

        $data['comment_status'] = "open";

    }

    return $data;

}
```

Also, I think that Codex is wrong as it says that `comment_status` is set to default comments status. It means that, if the custom post type supports comments and the default comment satus in WordPress configuration is open for new posts, any new post should have comments open by default but that is not happening if you remove the comment status meta box. That is why it is needed to override `comment_status` when the post is inserted.